# Django set settings from a non module directory

Tags: python, django

I'm using **Django 2.2**

My directory structure is

```
/
|- docs
|- scripts
|- src
   |- app
      |- settings
         |- __init__.py
         |- local.py
         |- development.py
      |- wsgi.py
   |- other_modules
   |- templates
   |- manage.py
|- Pipfile
|- Pipfile.lock
```

All the Django application is inside `src` directory (`src` is not a module).

I use `pipenv` to run the application from root directory as

```
pipnev run python src/manage.py runserver
```

I want to setup DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.development
```

But it gives `ModuleNotFoundError:`.

How can I set module from `src` directory, which is a non-module directory.

Comment: you need to create a __init__.py file inside src directory.

Comment: I created the file and used `src.app.settings.development` but it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Answer (score 1):

You are not starting it from the root directory. (`root` is where 'manage.py' is).

You also need a `__init__.py` file in the `app` folder

```
/
|- docs
|- scripts
|- src
   |- app
      |- settings
         |- __init__.py
         |- local.py
         |- development.py
      |- wsgi.py
      |- __init__.py
...
```